# Apple Watch never checks for heart attacks

Tags: apple-watch

One of the Apple Watch promotional material includes this image (apparently) from the health app.

[image: Apple Watch]

How can this be interpreted? I understand that the Apple Watch may alert for irregular heart rhythms, but what does this message means.

Comment: Wouldn't this mean the sensor in the watch isn't capable of detecting heart attack just like it can't detect fever or a broken leg. This seems pretty clear that it's intended to warn people what an ECG like sensor is able to record and predict / report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, this is really just a disclaimer that Apple Watch cannot detect heart attacks.

According to Apple:

> > **Things you should know**
>
> - Apple Watch cannot detect heart attacks. If you ever experience chest
>     pain, pressure, tightness, or what you think is a heart attack, call
>     emergency services immediately.
> - Apple Watch is not constantly looking for AFib. This means Apple Watch
>     cannot detect all instances of AFib, and people with AFib may not get
>     a notification.
> - If you’re not feeling well, you should talk to your doctor even if you
>     don’t get a notification. Symptoms such as a rapid, pounding, or
>     fluttering heartbeat, dizziness, or fainting, can indicate a serious
>     condition.
> - Do not change your medication without talking to your
>     doctor.
> - In some instances, the notification may indicate the presence of an
>     irregular heart rhythm other than AFib.

<sup>**Source:** [Heart rate notifications on your Apple Watch](https://support.apple.com/HT208931), Apple.</sup>